# Make an object disappear from another object in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to learn Unity and I want to make a simple game.I made most of the
game but I am stuck in one place.When the player touches another object then a third object should disappear.I made the collision detection but I can't get the
objects to communicate with each other.I tried gameObject.SendMessage but I 
couldn't get the third object to receive the message.I looked for other ways of
communicating between objects but I didn't understand them .I also tried running a script that makes the object disappear from the player object(I'm not sure it is possible)but it gave me some errors.
i don't need the most efficient way I just need one that works and is simple

Comment: It' not clear, what you want.Please provide some code showing what you have tried and what doesn't Work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need a way to reference the GameObject you want to disappear.
You can do that with various ways like searching by name or by tag, or by setting it in the editor.

For example, search by name, 
`GameObject objectToDisappear = GameObject.Find("ObjectToDisappearName");`

After that in order to make the object disappear you can disable its renderer by using
`objectToDisappear.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;` inside your collision detection method.

**EDIT**: To reference a GameObject, by dragging it in the inspector, create an instance variable inside the class from which you want to reference it. In your case it should be like this:

```
public class P2 : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject p3;

   void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) 
   { 
        if(col.gameObject.name == "p")
        {
           Debug.Log("Collision detected");
           p3.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
        }
   } 
}
```

Then, go in the inspector in the GameObject this script is attached (p2) and you should see that p3 value is empty (there should be a box that says "None(GameObject)" ) , just drag object p3(the one you want to hide) inside the box.

Comment: Note that `GameObject.Find` is CPU intensive and that there are other ways to reference objects that are faster, but the right one to use depends on your project.

Comment: I tried this and it said" Unexpected symbol GameObject".Here is the code: ` if(col.gameObject.name == "p")
        {
            Debug.Log("Collision detected");
            
            GameObject p3 = GameObject.Find("p3");
            
            
            

            
        }`i hope you can identify the problem!

Comment: @DiószegiZoltán It's hard to understand from the comments, but I don's see anything wrong with the code. I even tested it myself and it worked fine. Are you sure the error is in that line and not in some other part of your script?

Comment: using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;




public class p2 : MonoBehaviour {
 void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.name == "p")
        {
            Debug.Log("Collision detected");
            
            GameObject p3 = GameObject.Find("p3");
            
            
            

            
        }
    }

 // Use this for initialization
 } //this is the full code

Comment: @DiószegiZoltán I don't know what is wrong with the code, I tested it and I don't see anything wrong with GameObject. Is the error you have in run time or while compiling? Does the editor you use underline some part of your code?

Comment: Also p3 is a 3D text , can this be the source of the problem?

Comment: So, is it a UI element? Is it a child of your Canvas?

Comment: I clicked on the add object and I selected “3D Object”

Comment: @DiószegiZoltán I think that it still should work. Try referencing p3 by dragging it in the inspector instead of using GameObject.Find.

Comment: @DiószegiZoltán See the edit I made in my answer on how to do this.

Comment: @DiószegiZoltán I'm glad I could help! Since this answer helped could you please mark it as accepted, by clicking on the "tick" mark on the left of the answer?